# Why is my SKAudioNode giving me an error?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm getting the following error when playing a sound using `SKAudioNode` and `SKAction.play()`:

`2021-01-23 13:58:10.169108-0800 [AppNameHere][56755:10871021] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.h:323:entry: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2`

The sound *does* play, but the very first time it plays it causes the app to sort of jump/skip/pause for a moment. So, I'm getting an error accompanied by a pause.

Here's my code, which sits in a function that's called from `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`

```
//Load the sound
let audio = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "clink.wav")

//Prevent the sound from looping infinitely                
audio.autoplayLooped = false

//Add the sound to the scene                
self.addChild(audio)

//Play the sound
let playAction = SKAction.play()
audio.run(playAction)

//Wait for 1 second so the sound can complete, then remove it from the scene
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
   audio.removeFromParent()
}
```

Why is this problem happening, and how do I solve it?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**: I apparently need to "*Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question*."

*Desired behavior*: The sound should play without an error and without causing the app to jump/skip for a moment.

*Specific problem or error*: See error above.

*Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem*: See code above.

I've also added notes in the code to explain what each line does.

Comment: No idea what jank is, but could you say where your code is situated, is it all in didMove(to:)? What are you trying to achieve with the DispatchQueue code?

Comment: @JohnL Thanks for the feedback. I've removed the word "jank", explained where the code is situated, and explained what each line of code does (including the DispatchQueue bit). Hopefully this will get my question reopened.

Comment: Move all the lines above "audio.run(playAction)", into didMove(to view:), this is so it is built ready before you actually need it (so hopefully the pause will not happen). Change "audio.run(playAction)", to "audio.run(playAction, completion: {
                   audio.removeFromParent()
                })" this runs the action, then on completion removes it from parent. You can remove the DispatchQueue code as it is not needed.

Comment: @JohnL 1) I'm not sure how I would go about moving those lines into didMove(to:) because I need the sounds to play whenever there's a physicsBody collision, which are detected in didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact). Also, recall that there's an error that accompanies the pause. 2) When I remove the DispatchQueue code and instead use the "completion" strategy, my sounds do not play at all. Maybe that's because they're of a very short duration? I don't know.

Comment: Is didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) in the same swift file as didMove(to view:)?

Comment: @JohnL Yes it is. They're both in my GameScene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to get this working, if you want to use SKAudioNode then you could do the following.

Near the top of the GameScene file, create a variable:

```
var audio = SKAudioNode()
```

In "didMove(to view: SKView)" add the below lines:

```
audio = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "clink.wav")
audio.autoplayLooped = false
addChild(audio)
```

In your function (which gets called in your didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)), put the below lines in:

```
  let playAction = SKAction.play()
  let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
  let grp = SKAction.group([playAction, wait])
  let rfp = SKAction.removeFromParent()
  let sequence = SKAction.sequence([grp, rfp])
  audio.run(sequence)
```

Typically, you wouldn't need such an approach, but SKAction.play() doesn't seem to work with the completion: block, therefore i had to include a duration of 1 second (which is what you were happy doing before).
That should work.

Another approach, which is simpler, is:

```
var audio: SKAction?
```

Then in didMove(to view) put:

```
audio = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Clink.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Then in your function just put this:

```
  self.run(audio!, completion: {
    self.removeFromParent()
    })
```

Comment: The sound plays without causing a pause, now, but unfortunately the error remains. Also, could you explain why this strategy works? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When it comes to sound, you want to build (or preload), as much as possible into the didMove section. When it comes to actually playing the sound, you want to just play it, not start setting it up and playing it, that causes delays. My code could be improved, but to get the idea working it does the job. I'm not sure about the error, have you tried my 2nd appraoch to it? Thats typically what i would use for short sounds anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. Yes, I've tried the second approach, and I still get the error. But at least my app isn't freezing up anymore!